# Error in NS2.35 installation on fedora 17

Tags: networking, simulation, ns2

I'm trying to install NS2.35 on fedora 17 using allinone package.
I'm new to linux environment and have already spent many hours trying this. So far I've found out it is a problem with dependent packages. But I'm not able to figure out following error. 
Please help.

```
===========================================================
* Build Tclcl-1.20
============================================================
No .configure file found in current directory
Continuing with default options...
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lXbsd... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... yes
checking for dcgettext in -lintl... no
checking for getnodebyname in -ldnet_stub... no
checking that g++ can handle -O2... no
checking standard STL is available... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for strtoq... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking size of long... 8
checking for strtol... yes
checking for __int64_t... no
checking for long long... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking which kind of 64-bit int to use... int64_t
checking for tcl.h... -I../include
checking for tclInt.h... -I../include
checking for libtcl8.5... -L../lib -ltcl8.5
checking for init.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5
checking for http.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5/http1.0
checking Tcl http.tcl library... yes
checking for tclsh8.5.10... no
checking for tclsh8.5... ../bin/tclsh8.5
checking for tk.h... -I../include
checking for libtk8.5... -L../lib -ltk8.5
checking for tk.tcl... ../lib/tk8.5
checking for otcl.h... -I../otcl-1.14
checking for libotcl1.14... -L../otcl-1.14 -lotcl
checking for X11 header files
checking for X11 library archive
checking for XOpenDisplay in -lX11... yes
checking for XShmAttach in -lXext... yes
checking for zlib.h... -I/usr/include
checking for libz1.1.3... no
No explicit static compilation flag; setting V_STATIC to ""
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking system version (for system-dependent libraries)... Linux-3.3.4-5.fc17.x86_64
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
rm -f tcl2c++
g++   -o tcl2c++ tcl2c++.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [tcl2c++] Error 127
tclcl-1.20 make failed! Exiting ...
See http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html for problems
```

Many many thanks
-Uday

Comment: `g++: Command not found` - you need to install that (GCC C++ compiler)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
GCC is there installed, is there a problem with version of GCC ? Just read about it that for NS2.35 older version of GCC needed is it so ?

(I just checked, gcc 4.7 is installed currently. )

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a **C++** compiler installed. Some distros have multiple packages for GCC, maybe you don't have the right ones.

Comment: Ya, I installed it now using yum install gcc-c++
Then tried and it shows following error!

linkstate/ls.cc:396:28:required from here
linkstate/ls.h:137:20: error: ‘erase’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
linkstate/ls.h:137:20: note: declarations in dependent base ‘std::map<int, LsIdSeq, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, LsIdSeq> > >’ are not found by unqualified lookup linkstate/ls.h:137:20: note: use ‘this->erase’ instead make: *** [linkstate/ls.o] Error 1
Ns make failed!

Comment: Hello, I got the solution. A small modification was needed in the syntax in following file and it worked.

1. Go to ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/linkstate/
2. Edit ls.h
In line number 137, in place of void eraseAll() { erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }

make it void eraseAll() { this->erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }

3. Save the file and again run ./install